# Use the first positive number of a row if a certrain condition in another column is valid, using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to have the first non-negative number in a new column, based on three columns (`valueA, valueB, valueC`).

If a condition in `columnA` is valid. The condition is that `columnA!=None`.

An example of a dataframe (df):

```
columnA  valueA valueB valueC
None        -40    -41   -42
A           -5      10    20
B           -10     -5    10
C            1       2     3
```

The **result after the logic** would lead to:

```
columnA  valueA valueB valueC  valueD
None        -40    -41   -42    None
A           -5      10    20     10
B           -10     -5    10     10
C            1       2     3      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution, which is based on `numpy`:

```
d = df.iloc[:, 1:].values
v = d[np.arange(len(df)), np.argmin(d < 0, axis=1)]
df['valueD'] = np.where(df['columnA'].isnull(),  None, v)
```

Output:

```
  columnA  valueA  valueB  valueC valueD
0     NaN     -40     -41     -42   None
1       A      -5      10      20     10
2       B     -10      -5      10     10
3       C       1       2       3      1
```

Comment: In case I have several more columns I changed line 1 to: `df.iloc[:, [df.columns.get_loc(c) for c in ['valueA','valueB','valueC']]].values`

Comment: Or, alternatively: `d = df.filter(like='value').values`, @PV8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean masks and [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
tmp = df.drop(columns='columnA')
# or
# tmp = df.filter(like='value')
# or
# tmp = df[['valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC']]

df['valueD'] = (tmp.where(tmp.gt(0))
                   .bfill(axis=1)
                   .iloc[:, 0]
                   .where(df['columnA'].notna())
               )
```

Output:

```
  columnA  valueA  valueB  valueC  valueD
0     NaN     -40     -41     -42     NaN
1       A      -5      10      20    10.0
2       B     -10      -5      10    10.0
3       C       1       2       3     1.0
```

Alternative, pre-filtering the rows:

```
tmp = df.drop(columns='columnA')[df['columnA'].notna()]
# or
# tmp = df.loc[df['columnA'].notna(), ['valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC']]


df['valueD'] = (tmp.where(tmp.gt(0))
                   .bfill(axis=1)
                   .iloc[:, 0]
               )
```

You can also use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html):

```
df['valueD'] = tmp.where(tmp.gt(0)).stack().groupby(level=0).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def calculate_valueD(row):

  for i in row[1:]:
    if i >0:
      return i
```

and apply function to each row

```
df['valueD'] = df.apply(calculate_valueD, axis=1).fillna('None')
```